# Are there introductory reviews of trans-Planckian physics and inflation? Looking for something similar to Daniel Baumann's cosmology notes

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, resource-recommendations, quantum-gravity, cosmological-inflation

Are there introductory reviews of trans-Planckian physics and inflation? Looking for something similar to Daniel Baumann's cosmology notes - things are explained assuming minimal background.

Answer (score 1):

So, after a bit of 'Googling,' it looks like Brandenberger is the main person on this front with his and Martin's initial paper on it here: [The TransPlanckian problem of inflationary cosmology](https://inspirehep.net/literature/527770). However, I can not find any reviews that are on the level of Baumann's notes (which are really introductory cosmology, and trans-planckian studies are at their core, fundamental physics questions), except for a review done also by Brandenberger and Martin which (at face value) seems to be a good introduction into the issue both taking into account where the issue arises in theory, and where it can be found/constrained in experiment: [Trans-Planckian Issues for Inflationary Cosmology](https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.6753).

If you are wondering if either author (in a nice way) know what they are doing, and this isn't some random article from arXiv, Brandenberger is the person who started the entire field of string-gas cosmology (it is quite fun), while Martin is a true expert in inflation:
[Encyclopædia Inflationaris](https://inspirehep.net/literature/1223966).

Hope this helps, or at least points you in the direction you want, and has a tip, in the papers above, sometimes going through their references is more beneficial then going through the paper itself. Have fun!

Answer (score -2):

The first reason that there are noch reviews is that no Tranplanckian physics has ever been observed.

The second reason is this, but more controversial: it is highly improbable that transplanckian physics exists at all. One argument is given here: [www.motionmountain.net/physicscube.html](http://www.motionmountain.net/physicscube.html)
Another argument are the many paper about the transplanckian censorship conjecture. Transplanckian physics implies effects faster than light, smaller than the Planck length, or across a horizon. They are all hard to imagine.

Comment: Oh man, be very careful about citing motion mountain, there is a lot of nonsense in there.

Comment: On the cited page?

Comment: As promised on the Motion Mountain website, let me know what is wrong or misleading, and I will correct it.